# Use php require for local directory

Tags: php, runtime-error, require

I have recently been trying to add PHPMailer script to my site, following the accepted answer from here:

[Send attachments with PHP Mail()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail)

I have never used a require statment before so I assume I must be doing it wrong, currently testing on my local host version of the site. I have downloaded the entire zip of git (unzipped it) and moved it to the dir my scripts are in.

In my script I added the following line:

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php');
```

Which to my understanding was all I needed to do to use it. However I get this error:

> Warning:
>   require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\PHPMailer-master\class.phpmailer.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\include\mailer.php on line 10
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\PHPMailer-master\class.phpmailer.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\include\mailer.php on line 10

Any ideas what is causing this error? Am running PHP 5.6.21 if this is relevant.

Comment: try  require_once(dirname(  FILE  )).'/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php');

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the full path to the file, using realpath() - http://php.net/realpath, and use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get your current directory:

Comment: did you  use  like this format  require_once('../PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php');  ?

Comment: Yes. Also tried without the ../ to start. Did not change anything